# Understanding the purpose of a function for a class problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've submitted this code in class which goal was to find an average, and it came out correct:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

count = 0
total = 0
ans = 0

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    count = count + 1
    x = float(line[line.find(":") + 1 : ])
    total = x + total
ans = total / count 

print("Average spam confidence:", ans )
```

However, I'm trying to understand the true point of the functions listed below since total was set to zero:

```
total = x + total
```

In my head I'm thinking it's pointless adding zero. I tried doing the following however the code was incorrect:

```
ans = x / count
```

Comment: It only adds zero on the first iteration. Such a line is more usually written `total = total + x`, but either way, it adds `x`  to the current value of `total` (whether that be zero or not).

Comment: In this case since ```total``` was defined as zero, I'm still trying to understand its role in computing the ```ans``` since it was already zero.  Essentially, why couldn't I skip using the ```total``` function all together and just compute the ```ans``` by doing ```x / count```

Comment: Because `total` is the *accumulator*; it *starts* at zero, but then you add `x` to it on multiple iterations. When `total` starts at `0`, `total = total + x` is equivalent to `total = x`. On the next iteration, it *isn't* 0 anymore.